# Pagination - call to undefined method ::links

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to paginate data that's returned from a model.

But keep getting an error :

> Call to undefined method App\Shortlist::links()

Its on my Shortlist model and the code I'm using the paginate is (Controller)...

```
 public function shortlist()
    {
        $view_data = array
        (
            'shortlist' => Shortlist::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->with('property')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4)
        );

        $view = 'frontend.'.themeOptions().'.account.shortlist';

        // Change View Per Template...
        if(view()->exists($view))
        {
            // Shared View in the Templates...
            return view($view,  $view_data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Load Shared View...
            return view('frontend.shared.account.shortlist', $view_data);
        }
    }
```

Then in my view, I'm using :

```
{{ $shortlist->links() }}
```

But keep getting that error, any help as to why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$shortlist` is not defined, you need to return that collection to your view.

You can call `->links()` on a collection. `$view_data` is just an array, you want to access the `shortlist` collection in that array, so you need to call it like this

```
{{ $view_data['shortlist']->links() }}
```

Further why do you create this variable:

`$view_data = array
(
'shortlist' => Shortlist::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->with('property')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4)
);`

if you don't use it. If you don't use it I would just declare it like this:

```
$shortlist = Shortlist::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->with('property')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
```

and return that to your view, looks cleaner.